# common function between two arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I wanna find common elements between two arrays. my function does not work correctly.
arrays are sorted.
just wanna put two sorted arrays into the check_common function to show common elements.
anyone can help to fix it please!

```
void check_common (int x[], int size1, int y[], int size2)
    {
        int temp;
cout << " Common elements are:\t" << endl;
for ( int i=0; i <= size2; i++ )
{
    for ( int j=0; j <= size1; j++)
    {
        if (x[j] == y[j]){
            temp = x[j];
            cout << temp << "\t";}
    }   
}
cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: `for ( int i=0; i<y[i]; i++ )` I'm pretty sure that doesn't do what you think it does. For example, consider that the first element of your sorted `y` array is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution fails if in either array the items are not unique, because all other elements are shifted then.

The naïve solution is to use a `O(n)` check. Check for each element in array1 if it also exists in array2. Because the lists are sorted, doing this check is in `O(log(n))`.
Thus the overall runtime will be `O(nlog(n))` which is fairly okay.
If you can guarantee that each list item is unique, it can be done in `O(log(n))`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a 'homework', so here is suggestion.

1. You need to pass sizes of both arrays. Now, your loop is a never-ending one and the system will report an error for you or your program will hang.
2. Since you are having your both arrays sorted, then you can use two indices - one for the `x` and one for the `y` arrays. Move both pointers ahead whichever points to a 'lesser' value. You stop when both reach the array limit. Each time both pointers point to the same value, you print this out.

Something like this assuming that `nx` is size of `x` and `ny` size if `y`:

```
ix=0 ;
iy=0 ;
while ( ix < nx && iy < ny )
{
    if ( x[ix] == y[iy] )
    {
        std::cout << x[ix] << "\t" ;
        ix++ ;
        iy++ ;
    }
    else if ( x[ix] < y[iy] )
        ix++ ;
    else
        iy++ ;
}
```

I am leaving you with refining this function, and changing `check_common` function arguments.